# Mysqli, SELECT FROM, php

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to do a simple SELECT username FROM users from a database

```
$sql = "SELECT username
FROM users";

$select_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$parse_sql = mysqli_fetch_array($select_sql);
var_dump($parse_sql);
```

but it gives me this with var_dump while having multiple entries.

> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" ["username"]=> string(0) "" }

Other queries like this are working fine

```
$sql = "SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username ='$user'";
$select_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

I can't find what's wrong

Comment: you need to use loop

Comment: table name is different in queries

Comment: The `db_user` table has a row where `username` is an empty string. It's the first row returned by your query.

Comment: please consider using PDO rather than mysqli, you will thank me in the future

Comment: @Barmar thank you, that's it, but shouldn't the others appear?

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array()` just returns one row. If you call it again you'll get the next row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `while` loop to get all the users in db_user

```
$sql = "SELECT username
FROM db_user";

$select_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($parse_sql = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_sql))
{
  $usernames[] = $parse_sql
}

var_dump($usernames);
```

Comment: I'm gonna use it but what about foreach ?

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757316/use-a-foreach-loop-instead-of-while-with-myslqli-fetch-array

Comment: You have to use while coz it fetches one row at a time and if there are no rows it returns false.hence loop ends. whereas foreach iterates over each value of array

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_fetch_array` fetches only a single row from result set.

Consider using `mysqli_fetch_all` to get all results.

Also it is good to use results as associate array only by give

`mysqli_fetch_all($select_sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`